# Is it a misprint or a correct expression 'I could have also have called the method without brackets'?

Tags: expressions

I want to know the following sentence is correct or contains a misprint.

I could have also have called the method without brackets, as these are optional in Ruby and can make the syntax much more readable.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Why do you suspect a misprint? Are we supposed to investigate and unearth whether there's a misprint somewhere or even none? Come on, fonhorst, make the question clearer and we shall try to answer.

Comment: Btw, how is this off-topic? Am I missing something there again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a misprint, or a mistake at any rate, you only need one *have*. Both of these are grammatical:

> I could also have called the method without brackets, as these are optional in Ruby and can make the syntax much more readable.
>
> I could have also called the method without brackets, as these are optional in Ruby and can make the syntax much more readable.

Comment: +1, but is this a thing based on grammar or on usage?

Comment: @AtsutoNagatomo both. You don't say _I could have also have done_ any more than you say _I did also did do_.